# Upgrading from Windows Server 2012R2 to Windows Server 2016 RTM Issue

Tags: upgrade, windows-server-2016

I've tried twice to upgrade my machine from 2012R2 to 2016 RTM. Both times it failed with message

> 0x800F0830 - 0x20003
>   Windows Server 2016 the installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with
>   an error during INSTALL_UPDATES operation

I've already tried the those

- Use the sfc.exe to find if some errors and then repair missing or corrupted system files.
- Run dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth and dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth.

Can't actually try ( IT department )

- Disable the Anti-virus software from your system if you have any.

What do I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to upgrade without any further problems a long the way by doing this things:

- Don't install updates when asked about in the setup step
- Pulled the LAN cable after the setup prepared the machine and restarted for the first time.

I can't really recommend this solution based on facts. But in my case it did work flawlessly without any issues after the upgrade.

Comment: Worked without disconnecting the LAN, I also cleaned-up the old C:\$WINDOWS.~BT setup cache before starting setup without updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Choosing not to install updates at the beginning of the process and unplugging the unplugging the Ethernet also worked for me to get around this. Hallelujah!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error is quite often caused by lack of free space on your system drive. As you are doing in-place upgrade this process tries to create Windows.old folder for you, and possibly download and install updates.
Make sure that you have enough of free space or try to decline download and install updates if wizard asks you about this.
As per MSFT documentation: "Be aware that 32 GB should be considered an absolute minimum value for successful installation." (this is bare minimum space for clean install, in-place upgrade may require more space).

Comment: I've got 65 GB out of 112 GB free. Guess I'll have to wait 'til Microsoft fixed the issue based on the telemetry they receive.

Comment: I'm using the Storage Pool feature. What happens to this storage pool in case I'm doing a clean install instead of the in-place upgrade?

Comment: It is difficult to say, during in place upgrades from 2012 to 2012 R2 some people report pool entering into "Read-only by user action" state with some corrective actions required - see this: http://richardjgreen.net/storage-spaces-inaccessible-windows-server-2012-r2-upgrade/